# append multiple JSON files to single CSV

Tags: python, json, csv, append

In my Python code, I have a for loop that generates flattened JSON files.
I would like to append these JSON files recursively to a file (for example a .csv file) using the same for loop.

my final .csv should look like this:

```
{"name": "John", "age": 30, "married": true, "divorced": false, "children": ["Ann", "Billy"], "pets": null, "cars": [{"model": "BMW 230", "mpg": 27.5}, {"model": "Ford Edge", "mpg": 24.1}]}
{"name": "Doe", "age": 33, "married": true, "divorced": false, "children": ["Peter", "Billy"], "pets": null, "cars": [{"model": "Tesla", "mpg": 27.5}, {"model": "Ford Edge", "mpg": 27.1}]}
{"name": "Kurt", "age": 13, "married": true, "divorced": false, "children": ["Bruce", "Nikola"], "pets": null, "cars": [{"model": "Mercedes", "mpg": 27.5}, {"model": "123", "mpg": 24.1}]}
```

Comment: Are you aware what CSV stands for?

Comment: @KlausD.   yes, Comma Separated Value. Could you explain your question?
it will be only the extension of this file containing the list of the JSON ones

Comment: Are you trying to get a CSV output or JSON output? As your output expectations are for CSV with JSON sample.

Comment: a CSV file containing the list of all flattened JSON files in different rows

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to add all your data into a dictionary or other data structure like a list.

After that use the `csv` library to write a proper CSV file.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Tha will look like this.

I would use `;` considering you have a list of names separated by `,`.

But why not write it all in a JSON file instead of a CSV.

A CSV will look like this.

```
name;age;married;divorced;children;pets;cars
John;30;true;false;Ann,Billy;;model,BMW 230,mpg,27.5,model,Ford Edge,mpg,24.1

....
```

It is preferred to store it all in a JSON, so you can keep the data schema.

Anyways you need to store your data in a dict or a list and then write it to a JSON file with `json` library

https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

The json file will look like you said.

```json
{"name": "John", "age": 30, "married": true, "divorced": false, "children": ["Ann", "Billy"], "pets": null, "cars": [{"model": "BMW 230", "mpg": 27.5}, {"model": "Ford Edge", "mpg": 24.1}]}
{"name": "Doe", "age": 33, "married": true, "divorced": false, "children": ["Peter", "Billy"], "pets": null, "cars": [{"model": "Tesla", "mpg": 27.5}, {"model": "Ford Edge", "mpg": 27.1}]}
{"name": "Kurt", "age": 13, "married": true, "divorced": false, "children": ["Bruce", "Nikola"], "pets": null, "cars": [{"model": "Mercedes", "mpg": 27.5}, {"model": "123", "mpg": 24.1}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install and import pandas, then use a '.to_csv()'.

For ex.:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json (r'Path where the JSON file is saved\File Name.json')
df.to_csv (r'Path where the new CSV file will be stored\New File Name.csv', index = None)
```

You can find the documentation here -> [pandas.pydata.org](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/io.html#io-store-in-csv)

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it. I was already testing but I was doing something wrong:

```
csv_filename = csv_tst.csv

with open(input_folder_json_files, 'r') as json_one_line_read:
     json_one_line_file = json.load(json_one_line_read)     
        
with open(output_folder + csv_filename, 'a+', newline='') as csv_file:
     writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
     writer.writerow([json_one_line_file])
```

This part of the code is within the FOR-loop that creates flattened JSON files. Perhaps there are more elegant ways to do it, but it works.